# List ending with all elements being equal in Kotlin, interesting case

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I stumbled with an interesting case where i have something like this in the OnCreate method of my main activity:

```
val list = mutableListOf<TestObject.InnerObject> ()
val temp = TestObject.InnerObject
for (i in 0..15)
{
  temp.id = i

  Log.i ("id", temp.id)

  list.add (temp)
}

for (element in list)
{
  Log.i ("id", element.id)
}
```

TestObject is just this:

```
object TestObject { 
     object InnerObject { 
          var id = 0 
     }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why would the logs on the first for print correctly 0 to 15 but the logs in the second for are printing all equal ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object, `temp`, right? In the first loop, you're doing something to that object. Then you add it to the list - or to be more accurate, you add *a reference to it* to that list, something that *points at* your object.

Have a think about what the final list will look like. I'm gonna explain what's going on, but it's worth thinking about it first!

---

So you have your `temp` object. It looks like it's an `object` inside the `TestObject` class, so just a single object. You're not creating any new instances of it, you're just working with *the same object* the whole time.

As you loop, you change the `id` property on *temp*, and add *temp* to the list. This is *a reference to the object*, something that points at *temp* itself - it's **not** a *new, separate copy of `temp`*. You're not creating a snapshot of its current state. There's one *object*, and a bunch of *references* all pointing to it.

So as you increment `temp.id`, every item in your list will "see" that change - because every item is that specific object. You just have multiple references to it. When you finish (and when the second logging loop runs) you have *16* items, all that specific `temp` object, whose `id` value is now `15`.

You can probably work out the logging behaviour now! (I'm sure the question's already been answered anyway)

Comment: Thank you, i accept this as the answer not for being more right than others but for the extensive elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding reference to the same variable in memory to list - in the end you have list of 16 identical objects.

First log function call shows you untruthfully valid behavior, because you are printing temporary value with every for loop iteration, but
in second Log call you are printing final values. The same object must have the same values of the same field.

Answer (score 0):

`object` keyword means creating a Singleton object - an object which has only one instance in a program. In the first cycle `InnerObject.id` is changed for the same object and during that the logs print all the values. After the first cycle is finished the last value is set to `InnerObject.id` that is 15. In the second cycle you just print that value.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. But I think your answer implies this problem is specifically because of how `object` works. With how the OP's code is implemented, they'd see the same "problem" even if `InnerObject` was a regular `class`, because `temp` is never reassigned a new instance (not that it can be, given it's a `val`).

Comment: Thank you, i certainly was not thinking object keyword as being a Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

In the same object `temp` you are modifying `id`. So in first loop it printing 0 to 15, but for next loop it is printing the last value you assigned as the main object is same. If you want different value then you need to create new object of `TestObject` and assigned the value.